# HTML5 video size changes when loading another source

Tags: jquery, css, html, html5-video

I have a video on the website using the `<video>` tag.

I want to smoothly change the video source without the video appearing to glitch out for short amount of time.

Here's what I mean: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JffW2.gif

As you can see the video loses width/height during loading of a new source, I've put that red border to show the effect.

Code that can recreate the issue:

```html
<html>
<head>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<video preload="metadata" autoplay poster="data:image/gif,AAAA" class="preview-video" id="video" style="border: 5px red solid;">
 <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4" id="videoSource">
 Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
       <br />
<br />
<button id="loadOther">Next Video</button>   

<script>
 $("#loadOther").click(function() {
  $("#videoSource").attr("src", "http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4");
        $("#video")[0].load();
 });
</script>

 
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you want is really to avoid the width/height to return to defaults (300 x 150) when the next video is loading, you just have to set your `<video>`'s `width`and `height` properties to the ones of the loaded video (`videoWidth` and `videoHeight` are the real values of the media, not the ones of the element).

```js
// fix the element's width and height properties to the current video ones
$("#video").on('loadedmetadata', function() {
  this.width = this.videoWidth;
  this.height = this.videoHeight;
});

$("#loadOther").click(function() {
  $("#videoSource").attr("src", "http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4");
  $("#video")[0].load();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<video preload="metadata" autoplay poster="data:image/gif,AAAA" class="preview-video" id="video" style="border: 5px red solid;">
  <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4" id="videoSource">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
<br />
<br />
<button id="loadOther">Next Video</button>
```

However, this code will also change the width height of the element if the next loaded media doesn't have the same size as the previous one. To avoid it, just use `.one()` or remove the event listener once it has fired.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately this messes up mobile support, I'm using bootstrap and the video is in a bootstrap column.

Comment: Then try with `this.clientWidth` and `this.clientHeight` instead of videoWidth